# Python argument error occurs when running rdkit.Chem.SaltRemover(). (Python argument types did not match C++ signature)

Tags: python, rdkit, argument-error

I'm working on some tasks using `RDKit` and have some problems.
I'm trying to sanitize my dataset with `SaltRemover()` function but the `ArgumentError` occurs and I cannot figure out it.

The code used is this:

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
from rdkit.Chem.PandasTools import LoadSDF

A1 = LoadSDF('finaldata_A1.sdf', smilesName='SMILES')
A1 = A1['SMILES']

for mol in A1:
A1_mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(mol)
if mol is None: continue

from rdkit.Chem import SaltRemover
remover = SaltRemover.SaltRemover(defnFormat='smiles')
A1_mol_SR = remover.StripMol(A1_mol)
```

The error message after running the code is:

> ArgumentError: Python argument types in
>       rdkit.Chem.rdmolops.DeleteSubstructs(Mol, NoneType, bool)
>   did not match C++ signature:
>       DeleteSubstructs(class RDKit::ROMol mol, class RDKit::ROMol query, bool onlyFrags=False, bool useChirality=False)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a few things you are confused about here.

As for the `SaltRemover`, what are you trying to achieve with the `defnFormat` argument? When you use this argument you should also provide `defnData`, defining the salt that you want to remove i.e.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import SaltRemover

remover = SaltRemover(defnFormat='smarts', defnData="[Cl]")
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('CN(C)C.Cl')
res = remover.StripMol(mol)

# We have stripped the Cl
res.GetNumAtoms()
[Out]: 4
```

If you initialise the `SaltRemover`, without these arguments the salt definitions are read from a [file](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/blob/master/Data/Salts.txt) which is read as a set of SMARTS queries. When you set `defnFormat` to 'smiles', you are telling the remover to read the file as a series of SMILES strings. Of course, this file cannot be read as SMILES strings due to the comments and incorrect formatting. In the defined salts there is subsequently 'None' objects which is why you receive the `ArgumentError`. Internally rdkit is using the function `DeleteSubstructs` which is being passed your query molecule and the salt to be removed which now may be 'None'.

You may not require defining your own salts. If not just use the default arguments:

```
remover = SaltRemover()

# We can have a look at some of the salts
Chem.MolToSmarts(remover.salts[0])

[Out]: '[Cl,Br,I]'

# Use to strip salts
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('CN(C)C.Cl')
res = remover.StripMol(mol)
print(Chem.MolToSmiles(res))

[Out]: 'CN(C)C'
```

Your other problem seems to be with how you are handling the data. It seems like you are calculating the `Mol` objects twice? When you use the 'LoadSDF' function the Mols are added to the column with the name: 'ROMol' unless specified in the `molColName` argument. You are also only trying to strip one molecule? You should probably look at trying to apply your remover to the molecule column in the A1 dataframe.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation! It helped me with solving the `ArgumentError`. Anyway, I've gotten another problem with `SaltRemover` function... I tried to replace the 'ROMol' column using for-loop and `A1.iloc[:]['ROMol']`. But after running the code, I found that all the molecules in the 'ROMol' is replaced with the same one (the first molecule in the dataset). I am totally new to Python and RDKit so it's really hard to solve these problems all by myself :(

Comment: Glad I could help! If it helped you could you please mark it as the accepted answer? As for your other problem you should take a look at the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function. Off the top of my head something like A1['ROMol']. apply (remover.StripMol)